# Find all references recursively in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have huge list of constants. I want show where this all constants are used in throughout solution. I can check this (using find in solution) one by one but it will take lot of time.

is their any way so I can achieve this very quickly ?

Regards,
Sachin

Comment: I think using `shift+F12` might help

Comment: Do you use Resharper?

Answer (score 0):

There is a complete list of Visual Studio Shortcuts available here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx. As already mentioned the default shortcut for go to `Edit.FindAllReferences` is `Shift` + `F12`.

Also if you rightclick a symbol in your code you can find the available actions in the context menu (+ hotkeys to use them) which may be easier if you are new to Visual Studio, because the list is quite huge.

Answer (score 0):

**"Find all references"** is the easiest buit-in way to go, but that requires clicking through them one by one. "Find all references" can be accessed using the context menu or (by default) CTRL+K,R.

If you have VS2013 Ultimate and if your constants are in the same project or in the same file/class, you could use [**CodeMap**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238403.aspx). Right click on project/file and select "Show on Code Map". Or select Architecture-Generate dependency graph. This will draw you a graphical view of the usage. For example:

[image: Dependency graph]

You can then filter this Graph by Project/Namespace/Class level.

Also, **ReSharper** has built-in analyzing features:

[image: Resharper Analyze]

[Here's some documentation about ReSharper's features](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/project_level.html).

Answer (score -1):

May be you can try Alt + F12 [peek Definition]

Comment: No, that shows the single place where it is defined/declared, not all places where it is used.